# Can I create privileged and unprivileged containers simultaneously in the same machine?

Tags: linux, archlinux, lxc

I'm trying to create a privileged container and i already have set up my machine to run unprivileged containers, now i'm receiving the following error:

conf - conf.c:lxc_map_ids:2780 - newuidmap failed to write mapping "newuidmap: uid range [0-65536) -> [100000-165536) not allowed": newuidmap 8775 0 100000 65536 65536 0 1

Failed to write id mapping for child process

etc...

Answer (score 1):

The thing was to comment idmapping config lines in the lxc default.conf file located in /etc/lxc, in order to suscesfully run lxc-create command.